# Isotope Filter Errors / Troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I'm a novice coder and working on a personal website and was really hoping to use the isotope filter function in the portfolio section of my site. I've been having trouble with it however and was wondering if anyone might be able to provide guidance? I'm not sure whether it's my html or jquery at this point. Very much appreciated!

Thank you,
Joanna

HTML:

```
  <!--PORTFOLIO-->
  <section id="portfolio-section" class="text-left">
    <div class='container'>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="portfolio">
            <div class='container'>
              <div class="page-header text-center wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                <h2>Portfolio</h2>
                <h4>Increasing the accessibility & usefulness of data to decision-makers</h4>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="portfolio_content_area">
              <div class="portfolio_menu">
                <center>
                  <ul id="filters">
                    <li class="active_prot_menu"><a href="#porfolio_menu" data-filter=".datavis"><img src='images/data.png' height='13'>&nbsp;Data Visualisation & Reporting</a>&emsp;▪&emsp;</li>
                    <li><a href="#porfolio_menu" data-filter=".course"><img src='images/course.png' height='14'>&nbsp;Coursework</a>&emsp;▪&emsp;</li>
                    <li><a href="#porfolio_menu" data-filter=".art"><img src='images/art.png' height='14'>&nbsp;Artwork</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </center></div>

                <div class="portfolio_content" id="portfolio">
                  <div class='row' id="portfolio">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 nopadding">
                      <div class="pcontainer"><div class="datavis">
                        <img src="images/1-dv.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
                        <div class="overlay">
                          <div class="text"><a href="portfolio/tableau.html" target="_blank"><img src='images/data_white.png' height='17'><h1>LensShift</h1>
                            <p>Data visualisation of the depth and breadth of the LensShift Taxonomy.<br>By collaborating with my colleagues, I ensure the quality of data is appropriate for effective and creative visualisation.</p></a></details>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 nopadding">
                    <div class="pcontainer"><div class="datavis">
                      <img src="images/2-siobn.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
                      <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="text"><a href="portfolio/SIOBN_Michaelmas17-18_Impact_Report.pdf" target="_blank"><img src='images/data_white.png' height='17'><h1>SIOBN</h1>
                          <p>Monitoring & evaluating the Social Impact Oxford Business Network's (SIOBN) initiatives. Providing ongoing reporting to stakeholders on the relevance of activities.</p></a></details>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 nopadding">
                  <div class="pcontainer"><div class="course">
                    <img src="images/3-BSC.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
                    <div class="overlay">
                      <div class="text"><a href="portfolio/3-bsc.html" target="_blank"><img src='images/course_white.png' height='21'><h1>Skoll Academy</h1>
                        <p>Strategic consulting project with Big Society Capital investigating social investment models to address domestic violence in the UK.</p></a></details>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 nopadding">
                <div class="pcontainer"><div class="course">
                  <img src="images/4-EY.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
                  <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="text"><a href="portfolio/4-EY.html" target="_blank"><img src='images/course_white.png' height='21'><h1>Leadership</h1>
                      <p>A case study on the motivation and integration of EY's GigNow workforce.</p></a></details>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 nopadding">
              <div class="pcontainer"><div class="course">
                <img src="images/5-MedData.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="text"><a href="portfolio/5-MedData.html" target="_blank"><img src='images/course_white.png' height='21'><h1>Global Health Challenge</h1>
                    <p>A case study on using MedData™ to lower the burden of chronic diseases.</p></a></details>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 nopadding">
            <div class="pcontainer"><div class="art">
              <img src="images/6-insta.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
              <div class="overlay">
                <div class="text"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/joannamakescards_/" target="_blank"><img src='images/art_white.png' height='22'><h1>Art</h1>
                  <p>Stationery, Design, Lettering</p></a></details>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('.portfolio_menu ul li').click(function(){
    $('.portfolio_menu ul li').removeClass('active_prot_menu');
    $(this).addClass('active_prot_menu');
});

var $container = $('#portfolio');
$container.isotope({
  itemSelector: '.col-sm-4',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});
$('#filters').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
  var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  return false;
});
});
```

Comment: `center` HTML-tag is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks! I've removed the </center> double entry. The isotope filter function still doesn't work unfortunately.